# onclick in html image tag - pass string value to javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, image

Code:

// inside for loop..

```
$("#tabs").append('<li><a href="#tab' + 1 + '">' + 1 + '</a><img src="/Images/pdf.png" onclick="test('1s')" /></li>');

function test(val) {
    alert(val);
    //return false;
}
```

Please see this code `onclick="test('1s')"`. Is there any syntax wrong?. I am not able to pass the value `1s` to the `test` function.

But I can pass the value if it  is `1` instead of `1s`.

***UPDATE***:

How to pass a variable value...Lets say `1s` is in variable `val`.. If I put `onclick="test(\'val\')"`, I am getting the `val` as "val" instead of `1s`

**SOLUTION:**

I solved myself..Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/32945494/5409139

Answer (score 3):

You should escape single qoutes: `'` with a `\` symbol.

```
$("#tabs").append('<li><a href="#tab' + 1 + '">' + 1 + '</a><img src="/Images/pdf.png" onclick="test(\'1s\')" /></li>');
```

Comment: How to pass a variable...Lets say `1s` is in variable `val`.. If I put `onclick="test(\'val\')"`, I am getting the `val` as "val" instead of `1s`

Comment: Are you having any ideas / suggestions about the above question ?

Answer (score 1):

The code is in a single-quoted string argument, so the `''` around `1s` take you out of the string and back to the argument of the `append` function call.  Try `test(\'1s\')` (backslashes before each quote mark) instead.

More details of JavaScript strings are, e.g., [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp).

Answer (score 0):

This is simple bug.
Please do following...

```
$("#tabs").append("<li><a href='#tab" + 1 + "'>" + 1 + "</a><img src='/Images/pdf.png' onclick=\"test('1s')\" /></li>");

function test(val) {
    alert(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I added the quotes accordingly.

```
var val = "1s";
$("#tabs").append('<li><a href="#tab' + 1 + '">' + 1 + '</a><img src="/Images/pdf.png" onclick="test(\'' + val + '\')" /></li>');
```